# Image/file security approach

Tags: php, image, .htaccess, security

I have recently discovered that the following site http://pumpingbody.com/ uses feature which prevents users from viewing its image content unless one likes its fanpage on Facebook. This is relatively common approach and nothing extra ordinary here.

What strikes me is the fact that if you inspect the page source code and use direct image url, it displays notification image instead of the actual image to prevent non fb fans browsing site content.

Therefore my question is: How do they achieved the effect that based on some criteria, when users visit **exactly same url** to an image, they see **different file**? Is it htaccess based approach?

You should see two different images under this url, one for ordinary visitor and another for facebook fan:
http://pumpingbody.com/static/images/normal/000/007/9917b74cb34785c15f0eeec0603e8f39.jpg

Comment: It could be implemented by some sort of handler that checks the session ID from the cookie. If the session ID is of a user that is linked to a Facebook account that is a fan of the page then it allows access, otherwise it'll show the placeholder.

Comment: @SilverlightFox I understand how checking whether user liked facebook page or not is done. What I do not get is how the same url can display different content if its a link to jpg file

Comment: The handler processes the http request and returns the appropriate binary content for the image.

Comment: That gives impression of how this could be achieved. How would sample handler look like? Would it be driven by htaccess or server side (PHP for instance) only? Sample code or slightly more detailed approach as an answer would be appreciated